# MVC implement security to prevent accessing other users information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, primary-key, asp.net-identity

I am familiar with roles and authentication attributes in MVC, but as I am adding more and more information onto my database I think I ma going to run into a problem with primary keys being unencrypted or accessible.

I am using identity 2.1, so when a user is logged in I have access of their UserId and their CustomerID but my concern is that any user can go to /Customers/Delete/3 or any CustomerID and have access. Even if I created a GUID id or other encryption it could still be vulnerable to brute force attacks.

Is there a way in MVC to implement a check to only allow the current user to load pages that are related to them?

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra field say `"CreatedByUserId"` to database table and when user access page check if `CreatedByUserId` matches with user id of logged in user or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the current logged in user has access to any of the information before you try and manipulate data. For example...

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteCustomer(string customerId)
            {
                var appUser = await _authRepository.FindUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());

                  if(!_customerRepository.CanDeleteCustomer(appUser.Id, customerId){
                 return BadRequest();
                  }
                  // they have access so do what you need to do down here..
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Authorize Attribute` and a table in the database in which you store which user is allowed what Pages (Actions) or Controllers and then check that table while authorizing that whether the user is authorized for that Page/Controller. I have created an example for you in which I used `Custom Authorize Attribute` named `MyAuthorizeAttribute` and a database table named `PageRoles`.

**Custom Authorize Attribute:**

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    string _pageName;
    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(string pageNameFromController)
    {
        _pageName = pageNameFromController;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var pageRoles = db.PageRoles.Where(m => m.UserId == userId);
        foreach (var item in pageRoles)
        {
            if (item.PageName == _pageName && item.UserId == userId)
            {
                return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Model used:**

```
public class PageRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and then you will just have to use the attribute on your controllers just like you use `Authorize` attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ }
```

Comment: Where would be the best place to add the "Custom Authorize Attribute"? Its just going to be a "New class" that can be placed in any folder isnt it? 
It doesnt seem to let me override "AuthorizeCore"

Comment: @failsatheals
- Where would be the best place to add the "Custom Authorize Attribute"?
yes you can add it anywhere just make sure to reference it in your controller.
- It doesnt seem to let me override "AuthorizeCore"?
Why ? What is the problem you are having? Because if you are inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` it will let you override `AuthorizeCore`.